Auto-Incrementing text field labels QGIS
I am trying to create points in QGIS & Qfield that auto-increment. For instance, Ground Control Points for drone data, "GCP-001, GCP-002... and so on" to display on the map label.
Another format I am interested in creating would be for grid stations such as, "L-01 STN-0+050, L-01 STN-0+100... & so on".
This is for mineral exploration surveys and would hold a considerable value to achieve.

what "data provider" are you using, geopackage or postgis or ? If it were me, I would configure this in postgis and QGIS should reflect that. Not sure how to configure in other providers.
